# Storing key/value pairs on disk using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a bunch of key/value pairs I'd like to cache for my WPF application. In Silverlight this is deliciously easy - I can just do:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings userSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
wombat = (string)userSettings["marsupial"];
```

Is there anything like this in WPF? A wombat may not be a marsupial, now I think about it. Some work needed there.

Edit: I would like if I can to avoid serialising these to/from en masse, as there are going to be a very large number of them with large amounts of data in them (I'm caching web pages).

Comment: You could simply use the implementation provided by the moonlight project. http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/2.6.4-mono-.net-core/System.IO/System/IO/IsolatedStorage/IsolatedStorageSettings.cs.htm

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `IsolatedStorageSettings` doesn't exist in the desktop version of the .NET Framework, it's only available in Silverlight. However you can use `IsolatedStorage` in any .NET application; just serialize a `Dictionary<string, object>` to a file in isolated storage.

```
var settings = new Dictionary<string, object>();
settings.Add("marsupial", wombat);

BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly();

// Save
using (var stream = store.OpenFile("settings.cfg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
{
    formatter.Serialize(stream, settings);
}

// Load
using (var stream = store.OpenFile("settings.cfg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read))
{
    settings = (Dictionary<string, object>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
}

wombat = (string)settings["marsupial"];
```

Comment: Just want to warn on this one, Isolated Storage will not work on machines where your administrator has set the machines for FIPS encoding.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811833 .  You'll have to figure your own encryption method out that way.

Answer (score 6):

If by WPF, you mean the full .Net runtime, then yes. There's a default Settings class created with the WPF project template.
[Settings class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

See this [discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/wpf-disciples/browse_thread/thread/4ed6c009f3fb7d69)

It doesn't exist in WPF but can easily be ported from Mono's moonlight implementation (http://vega.frugalware.org/tmpgit/moon/class/System.Windows/System.IO.IsolatedStorage/IsolatedStorageSettings.cs)

```
    //Modifications at MoonLight's IsolatedStorageSettings.cs to make it work with WPF (whether deployed via ClickOnce or not):

// per application, per-computer, per-user
public static IsolatedStorageSettings ApplicationSettings {
  get {
    if (application_settings == null) {
      application_settings = new IsolatedStorageSettings (
        (System.Threading.Thread.GetDomain().ActivationContext!=null)?
          IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication() : //for WPF, apps deployed via ClickOnce will have a non-null ActivationContext
          IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly());
    }
    return application_settings;
  }
}

// per domain, per-computer, per-user
public static IsolatedStorageSettings SiteSettings {
  get {
    if (site_settings == null) {
      site_settings = new IsolatedStorageSettings (
        (System.Threading.Thread.GetDomain().ActivationContext!=null)?
          IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication() : //for WPF, apps deployed via ClickOnce will have a non-null ActivationContext
          IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly());
          //IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForSite() works only for Silverlight applications
    }
    return site_settings;
  }
}
```

Note that you should also change the #if block at the top of that code to write

## if !SILVERLIGHT

Also take a look at this for [custom settings storage](http://f10andf11.blogspot.gr/2012/03/wpf-implement-isolatedstoragesettings.html)

Comment: You might want to give an explanation on why you would use this method rather than the accepted answer above, which uses internal .Net code already.